# Bootstrap 4 Modal Hide Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap v3.3.7 the below code works fine.  I have recently attempted to upgrade to Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2 for some reason it no longer works.

What I am doing is showing a modal div that has as a spinner on it. I then go and load the rest of page and when all done loading the rest of the page I close the modal div.  Again worked fine in v3, no longer works in v4.  I can however open the console and run $("#divLoading").modal('hide'); and the div goes away.

FIDDLE Boostsrap v4 [BROKE]: https://jsfiddle.net/gc1097oh/ 
FIDDLE Bootstrap v3 [WORKS]: https://jsfiddle.net/7skoLo2q/

```
 <div id="divMain" class="Main">
                <div id="divLoading" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="loader">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        loading div actual div has a spinner but not need to show error
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-dialog invisible">

                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        showLoading();
        //do some work then hide
        hideLoading();
    });


    function showLoading() {
        $('#divLoading').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        });
    }

    function hideLoading() {
        $("#divLoading").modal('hide');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think it has something do with asynchronous methods. You cannot trigger the hide method when the modal is in a transition state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modals are created in an asynchronous manner, but you are calling your `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` functions in a synchronous way. You can check if the modal has been displayed already in your hideLoading function like so:

```
function hideLoading() {
    $('#divLoading').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#divLoading").modal('hide');
    })
}
```

Comment: So it sounds like the hideLoading() is getting called before the modal is fully displayed?  With the solution provided that only works if all the page loading functions happen before the modal is displayed.  Is there a solution that takes care of both scenarios?

Comment: Answering my own question above the hideLoading() function could be like the following.  But is there a better approach?<br>   function hideLoading() {
            $('#divLoading').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $("#divLoading").modal('hide');
            })

            $("#divLoading").modal('hide');
        }

Comment: Because of how Call Stack works in javascript, hideLoading will always be called before the moment the modal creation happens asynchronously. Thus the callback will be always added to the 'shown.bs.modal' event before the modal is displayed.